# Why does the difference Boolean not work with high subdivision levels?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode, shadows

I am trying to use the difference Boolean modifier to remove a smooth curved shape from another smooth curved shape, but Blender will only do it when the subdivisions are so low that the quality is terrible. I know I could use shade smooth but you can still see the harsh lines and I want a smoother look. What causes the modifier to fail?

Unless perhaps I am missing something but from what I can tell, the subdivisions are fighting the boolean and I am curious as to how they even relate. I figured more geometry would make it easier for the boolean to bind the new geometry.

If you're curious about the project I am working on, I posted the question yesterday

Comment: Please add some screen shot. That will help the viewer understand the specifics of your problem.

Comment: @Bruno I have added all the details with screenshots in my prior post. This post is simply asking what's going on behind the scenes in Blender to cause the issue. My other post is asking how to fix it.